# create table dynamically in python (mysql.connector)

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have a website where I need to create tables dynamically. I'm using mysql.connector and getting an error when I try to execute a CREATE SQL statement. The following is an example of my code:

```py
import mysql.connector

db = mysql.connector.connect(user='root',
                             password='mypassword',
                             host='127.0.0.1',
                             database='database_name')

sql = '`col1` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, `col2` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, `col3` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,'
col_name = 'users'

with db.cursor(buffered=True, dictionary=True) as c:
    c.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE `tb_%s` (
            `product_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `description` VARCHAR(255), 
            %s
        );
    ''', (col_name, sql,))
    db.commit()
```

With this code, I get this error:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''`col1`
> VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL'
> )' at line 4

I was expecting my code to be executed like this SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_%s` (
        `product_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `description` VARCHAR(255), 
        `col1` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, 
        `col2` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, 
        `col3` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    );
```

With this syntax, I'm able to create the table:

```
with db.cursor(buffered=True, dictionary=True) as c: 
        c.execute('''CREATE TABLE `tb-userss` (
            `product_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `description` VARCHAR(255), 
            `%s` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY(`product_id`));''', ('col1',))
        db.commit()
```

But, It isn't util because the number of columns is variable

Comment: You cannot use placeholders/prepared statements for table names and columns, only with values. Besides that, in your sql, you have an extra comma (,) at the end

Comment: "I have a website, where I need to create tables dynamically"—this is almost always the wrong decision. Why do you want to do this? There's probably a better solution.

Comment: Chris, I am developing an internal dashboard, to control stock. The products are separated in categories. I thought a new table should be easier to control the products, because each category has your own parameters, so what would be a better solution for this? These parameters would be the columns in db. And, my objective is give the admin the power to create new categories.

Comment: Nacho, I noticed this, but the same error persists

Answer (score 0):

Coding around, I find 'format' method and use it to create the table.

```
import mysql.connector

db = mysql.connector.connect(user='root',
                              password='mypassword',
                              host='127.0.0.1',
                              database='databasename')

columns = '`col1` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,`col2` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,`col3` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,'

sql = '''
        CREATE TABLE `tb_userss` (
            `product_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `description` VARCHAR(255), 
            {}
            PRIMARY KEY(`product_id`));
        '''.format(columns)

with db.cursor(buffered=True, dictionary=True) as c: 
    c.execute(sql)
    db.commit()
```

I don't know if it's a good idea use format. In docs, they use %s and I see this syntax being used most of the time. I think %s prevent sql injection.

Comment: You should avoid using format for _values_, in select, insert or update statements. However for DDL statements like `CREATE TABLE` format is ok (as long as you aren't formatting untrusted data.

Comment: Good to know it! Thanks ;). In the others statements, I'll keep using with %s. But I have no idea why %s doesn't work to pass the column name

Comment: SQL distinguishes between _identifiers_ like table and column names, and _values_ (the values that you insert into or read from the database).  Character (string) values must be quoted with single quotes, but identifiers are quoted (if necessary) with double quotes.  The values in `cursor.execute(sql, values)`  are quoted as _values_; if you try to use column names there you will get an error be the quoting is wrong.

Comment: btw MySQL can be configured to use back ticks rather than double quotes for identifiers, to add to the fun. Search fro "identifiers" in the MySQL docs).